# Range.Interior.Color error when Range has merged cells.

Tags: excel, vba

Why does the following row work:

```
    Range("A1,B2").Interior.Color = someColorAsLong
```

And the following doesn`t:

```
    dim someVariableName as Long
    someVariableName = Range("A1,B2").Interior.Color
```

I have even tried with specifying the active sheet, the workbook and active sheet.. I sometimes get out of range exception (still 1004), but mostly the method of object global failed (1004).

Comment: The above lines are being executed in a sub called from the code of a button click (button is on active sheet)

Comment: when you run your second line are the colors of `A1` and `B2` the same? This will return zero if they are not identical.

Comment: Works for me. I mean it doesnt give any error. In what scenarios does it give an error?

Comment: Brad: the colors are the same. I even tried with simply Range("A1")... Interesting is that if I use the Sheet("name") I get index out of range

Siddharth Rout: I do have merged cells. The A1 has A1..C1 together and the B2 has B2..C2 together. I can`t get it to work.. will try with a new document

Comment: works in a different document... oh my god, what did this microsoft sewage company put on market?..... thanks guys for all your help

Comment: Please do not bitch about MS Products. If you don't like it. Stop using it :) IMHO, VBA by far is the best programming language that is available in the market for Office Products ;)

Comment: I appreciate your frustration, but I wouldn't use such a philosophical title for the question.. It downgrades its quality, and its an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your error in the following case:
Insert a chart sheet (did it manually) and leave it active. Now your code will always return `Method Range of object _Global failed (1004)`

[image]

This is one possible answer for the error you got. To avoid this error be sure to specify the workbook and worksheet explicitly.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
someVariableName = ws.Range("A1,B2").Interior.Color
```

Specifying the workbook and worksheet explicitly is better than using `ActiveSheet` because the user could have a chart sheet active. Although in your case, you have the code on the worksheet so that shouldn't happen.

Comment: I reached the conclusion that the excel document was corrupt. I don`t know why, but it works in a different document. I have copied all my macros in the new document, created buttons for each of them and everything works smooth. The previous document was created by me, in excel 2010 (not converted from previous version of excel), it has no pivot tables, no filters, no hidden rows/columns, no nothing, it`s just a simple excel sheet with data and colors in some cells. Columns and rows have no problems. Yet, a new excel document does it. I`d swear at microsoft right now.. 5 hours lost debugging..

Comment: Well go figure. Sounds crazy but that's MS. Best wishes!